# Accessing variables in the parent via pointer after clone()

Tags: c, clone

I'm sorry for possibly asking an idiot question, but i'm a bloody beginner in C.
Now my problem is, i need to access two variables, declared in main, in a child process and modify them.
Sounds very simple, but i have to use clone and after backcasting the variables to my array, they are completely messed up concerining the value.

```
int main (){
uint64_t N = 10000000;
uint64_t tally = 0;
int status;

void** child_stack = (void**)malloc(65536);
uint64_t** package = (uint64_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t*)*2);
package[0] = &tally;
package[1] = &N;

pid_t cpid;
cpid = clone(child_starter, &child_stack, CLONE_VM , (void*)package);
waitpid(cpid, &status, __WCLONE);
return 0;
}
```

the child_starter functions looks as follows:

```
int child_starter(void* package){
printf( "Tally is in the child %" PRIu64 "\n", *((int64_t**)package)[0] );
return 0;
}
```

since tally is 0, i thought my printf should actually print out 0, but it's more like 140541190785485
changing from run to run..

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: `clone` is very low-level. Is there a reason not to use pthreads or the like?

Comment: you **need not** and **should not** cast the return value of `malloc`. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: i have to use clone, it's in the task. pthreads would be much easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `child_stack` already is a pointer to valid memory, so do not pass its address, but its value.
- Stack grows top to bottom, at least on nearly all Linux implementations, so the stack pointer passed needs to be the end of the memory allocated for the stack.

```
cpid = clone(child_starter, ((char *) child_stack) + 65536, CLONE_VM , package);
```

Also in C there is not need to cast to `(void*)`.

Also^2 `printf()` isn't reentrant so it's use here is error prone.

Comment: @user3077638: You are welcome. If you think this answers your question you might mark it as such. If you also like it, you are free to upvote this answer too.