# How to wait for threads to finish their work, where threads created by clone in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, wait, waitpid

I try to wait the main function, till the threads finish their work. But the main function finish its work and exit. I think because of that the threads has not the correct pointers/values in the variables.(tally and steps)

Does someone know how to use waitpid/wait properly in this case?

my Code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h> /* for PRIu64 and uint64_t */
/* you'll need further includes */
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tally.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 32768
#define THREADS 2
struct clone_args{
        uint64_t steps;
        uint64_t* tally;

};
int incHelper(void* arg){
        struct clone_args *args = (struct clone_args*)arg;
        uint64_t steps= args->steps;
        uint64_t* tally = args->tally;
        increment(tally,steps);
        (void) arg;
        (void) tally;
        (void) steps;
        exit(2);
        return 0;
}

int main ()
{
        uint64_t N = 10000000;
        uint64_t tally = 1;
        tally_init();
        int thread_pid[THREADS];
        int status;
        for(int i= 0; i<THREADS;i++){
                void *child_stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
                struct clone_args *arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct clone_args));
                arguments->steps = N;
                arguments->tally = &tally;
                void* arg = (void*) &arguments;
                thread_pid[i] = clone(incHelper, child_stack+STACK_SIZE,CLONE_VM, arg);
                pid_t pid = waitpid(thread_pid[i],&status,SIGCHLD);
                printf("C-PID [%d]\n", thread_pid[i]);
                (void) pid;
        }

        tally_clean();
        printf( "\nTally is %" PRIu64 "\n", tally );
        (void) N;
        (void) thread_pid;
        (void) tally;
        (void) status;
        printf("\n MAIN PROGRAMM END\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The increment function:

```
/* modify this function to achieve correct parallel incrementation */
void  increment ( uint64_t *tally, uint64_t steps )
{
        printf("\nTALLY: %"PRIu64"\n",*tally);
        printf("STEPS: %"PRIu64"\n",steps);
        for( uint64_t i = 0; i < steps; i++ )
        {
                *tally += 1;
        }
        return;

}
```

The Result i got after running the code:

```
C-PID [29819]
C-PID [29820]

Tally is 1

 MAIN PROGRAMM END
root@...(~/Downloads/asst3/asst3-clone)$
TALLY: 0
STEPS: 140714329004032

TALLY: 888309
STEPS: 140714329004032
```

The code should increment a variable with two threads. To avoid criticalsection Problem i should use semaphores. But thats an other exercise. First exercise it to use clone() function to create two threads. I dont understand, if the flags of clone() are wrong or my code is completely wrong. I am new at programming language C.

I spent last 12 hours of searching with google.

I thank for every answer :).

Sorry for bad english.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20442072/694576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per default a `clone()`ed process does not signal the parent about its end.

If you want the parent to be signalled about the child's end you need to explicitly pass the signal to be sent on its end when `clone()`ing ORed to the 3rd parameter passed.

If you use `SIGCHLD` then use `waitpid()` as usual.

In this latter case clone and wait like so:

```
  thread_pid[i] = clone(incHelper, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, arg);
  pid_t pid = waitpid(thread_pid[i], &status, 0);
```

If you want to use another signal to be sent on the child's end like for example `SIGUSR1` you need to tell this to `waitpid()` using the option `__WCLONE`:

```
  thread_pid[i] = clone(incHelper, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM | SIGUSR1, arg);
  pid_t pid = waitpid(thread_pid[i], &status, __WCLONE);
```

---

This

```
void* arg = (void*) &arguments;
```

takes the address of `arguments`. As `arguments` already is an address of the required structure, it should be:

```
void * arg = arguments;
```

---

Note: As the main thread `waitpid()`s for the `clone()`ed thread to finish before the next call to `clone()`, there is **no** parallel processing of `increment()`

Comment: Sorry i translated it wrong. In English the error called Segmentation fault Error. The error occurs after i inserted SIGCHILD and set the third argument to zero, of waitpid.

Comment: Thx a lot :D Tally ?? :D hmm i wish i'd know that :D